# Missing operator or semicolon in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've got the error message "Missing operator or semicolon" on line 38 of this code:

```
procedure TForm1.SpinEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case SpinEdit1.Value of
    1: Label6.Caption('rok'); // line 38
  end;
end;

end.
```

Does somebody know what I am missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `Label6.Caption := 'rok';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Label6.Caption('rok')
```

`Caption` is a [property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties) which behaves as a variable does. You treat it as though it is a procedure (which it is not) and hence the compilation error. The parser knows that the only thing that can follow a property name is a semicolon, bracket (if the property is indexed) or an operator like `:=`, `+`, `=` etc.

This code would compile:

```
Label6.Caption := 'rok';
```

Perhaps that's what you meant.